# StratifiedKfold over heterogeneous DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a pandas DataFrame which contains string and float columns that needs to be split into balanced slices in order to train a sklearn pipeline.

Ideally I'd use [StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html) over the DataFrame to get smaller chunks of data to cross validate. But it complains that I have unorderable types, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold

dataset = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'title': 'Dábale arroz a la zorra el abad', 'size':1.2, 'target': 1},
        {'title': 'Ana lleva al oso la avellana', 'size':1.0, 'target': 1},
        {'title': 'No te enrollé yornetón', 'size':1.4, 'target': 0},
        {'title': 'Acá sólo tito lo saca', 'size':1.4, 'target': 0},
    ])
skfs = StratifiedKFold(dataset, n_folds=2)

>>>  TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()
```

There are ways to get folds indices and do slicing over the DataFrame, but I don't think that guarantees that my classes are going to be balanced.

What's the best method to split my DataFrame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold` is deprecated since version 0.18 and will be removed in 0.20. So here is an alternative approach:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)
t = dataset.target
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(np.zeros(len(t)), t):
    train = dataset.loc[train_index]
    test = dataset.loc[test_index]
```

Comment: Using `iloc` is probably more general, since I think `train_index` and `test_index` give row numbers

Answer (score 9):

`StratifiedKFold` requires the number of splits, and the `.split()` method uses the label's class distribution to stratify the samples. Assuming your `label` is `target`, you would:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)
X=dataset.drop('target', axis=1)
y=dataset.target
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
```

Comment: Deprecated since version 0.18: This module will be removed in 0.20. Use sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold instead.

Comment: or, without dropping anything from the dataset just do `skf.split(dataset, dataset.target)`